# Continuously process child process' outputs byte for byte with a BufReader

Tags: rust, process, command, pipe

I'm trying to interact with an external command (in this case, exiftool) and reading the output byte by byte as in the example below.
While I can get it to work if I'm willing to first read in all the output and wait for the child process to finish, using a BufReader seems to result in indefinitely waiting for the first byte. I used [this example](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/os/external.html#continuously-process-child-process-outputs) as reference for accessing stdout with a BufReader.

```rust
use std::io::{Write, Read};
use std::process::{Command, Stdio, ChildStdin, ChildStdout};

fn main() {
    let mut child = Command::new("exiftool")
        .arg("-@") // "Read command line options from file"
        .arg("-") // use stdin for -@
        .arg("-q") // "quiet processing" (only send image data to stdout)
        .arg("-previewImage") // for extracting thumbnails
        .arg("-b") // "Output metadata in binary format"
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn().unwrap();

    {
        // Pass input file names via stdin
        let stdin: &mut ChildStdin = child.stdin.as_mut().unwrap();
        stdin.write_all("IMG_1709.CR2".as_bytes()).unwrap();
        // Leave scope:
        // "When an instance of ChildStdin is dropped, the ChildStdin’s underlying file handle will
        // be closed."
    }

    // This doesn't work:
    let stdout: ChildStdout = child.stdout.take().unwrap();
    let reader = std::io::BufReader::new(stdout);
    for (byte_i, byte_value) in reader.bytes().enumerate() {
        // This line is never printed and the program doesn't seem to terminate:
        println!("Obtained byte {}: {}", byte_i, byte_value.unwrap());
        // …
        break;
    }

    // This works:
    let output = child.wait_with_output().unwrap();
    for (byte_i, byte_value) in output.stdout.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("Obtained byte {}: {}", byte_i, byte_value);
        // …
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @FrancisGagné That solved it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not closing the child's stdin. Your `stdin` variable is a mutable reference, and dropping that has no effect on the referenced `ChildStdin`.

Use `child.stdin.take()` instead of `child.stdin.as_mut()`:

```
    {
        // Pass input file names via stdin
        let stdin: ChildStdin = child.stdin.take().unwrap();
        stdin.write_all("IMG_1709.CR2".as_bytes()).unwrap();
        // Leave scope:
        // "When an instance of ChildStdin is dropped, the ChildStdin’s underlying file handle will
        // be closed."
    }
```